# Export Polygon generated with Geometry Generator as dissolved polygons

Tags: qgis, export, geometry-generator

Absolute QGIS newbie (3.10.8) here, so please bear with me.

I got a QGIS document where some polygons (countries) are virtually dissolved in regions (like South America), through a rule-based symbology and styled as one polygon with the geometry generator.

`buffer (collect($geometry), ' ',(array_contains(array("Reg1" ,"Reg2" , "Reg3"),'Region_name'))),0)`

I want to export a file (preferably .shp) of these regional objects into dissolved polygons based on the attribute "region_name" when it occurs in one of the fields "Reg1", "Reg2", "Reg3", some countries being part of several political or economical region (South America as a geographical ensemble where some of the countries belong to a specific economical institution and some other not)

How do I do that?

Edit: Value and field names, explanations

Comment: Is the actual data separated into individual countries ("Region" field) but the symbology is set to that expression? Or is it a virtual layer?

Comment: This is a basic shapefile with the countries' border whose symbologie is driven by this expression, not a virtual layer. Some countries will belong to different overlapping regions

Answer (score 5):

There is a very cool tool in QGIS called [`Geometry by expression`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression). You find it under <kbd>Menu Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>Geometry by expression</kbd>.

It allows you to convert the geometries created with geometry generator (for visualization purpose only) to actual geometries. You can use the same expression as in Geometry generator - [see here for more details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814).